# Change state hook being called the second time function is called

Tags: reactjs, parse-platform

I am trying to build this auth system using Back4App as backend, for which I use the useState hook for storing the Input email. The first time the handleSubmit is called, it doesn't work (doesn't log on the console and doesn't show up on the database),  but when it is called the second time, it works as intended.
Here's the complete code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Parse from "parse/node";
import {
  Button,
  Input,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  IconButton,
  Typography,
  Box,
  Grid,
} from "@material-ui/core";

Parse.initialize(
  "7lgNpft2XSQJkk0dxf0oluQB7NtPTsNBp84opurx",
  "6mFJYrSwI7iYtYQAn4E1qJVLlf0LWd4i0nX4CP7F"
);

Parse.serverURL = "https://parseapi.back4app.com/";

const App = () => {
  const [email, changeEmail] = useState("");
  const [metaEmail, changeMetaEmail] = useState("");

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    changeMetaEmail(value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (re.test(metaEmail)) {
      changeEmail(metaEmail);
      console.log(email);
      console.log(metaEmail);
      var Person = Parse.Object.extend("Person");
      var person = new Person();
      person.set("email", email);
      person.save();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="mainContainer">
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar variant="dense">
          <Typography>{email}</Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Grid container justify="center">
        <Box classes="inputArea" margin="2rem">
          <Grid container xs="10rem">
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => {
                handleInput(e);
              }}
            ></Input>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container justify="center">
            <Box margin="10px">
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                onClick={() => {
                  handleSubmit();
                }}
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you add complete code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, turned out it was because the 'email' was being changed afterI called the console log and pushing it to the server. I worked around it by using a 'useEffect' hook being called whenever email updated, so now it works only after the email has actually been changed.

If anyone has a better alternative please let me know!

Here's the working code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Parse from "parse/node";
import {
  Button,
  Input,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  IconButton,
  Typography,
  Box,
  Grid,
} from "@material-ui/core";

Parse.initialize(
  "7lgNpft2XSQJkk0dxf0oluQB7NtPTsNBp84opurx",
  "6mFJYrSwI7iYtYQAn4E1qJVLlf0LWd4i0nX4CP7F"
);

Parse.serverURL = "https://parseapi.back4app.com/";

const App = () => {
  const [email, changeEmail] = useState();
  const [metaEmail, changeMetaEmail] = useState();

  // let re = new RegExp(/[a-z]+@+[a-z]+.+[a-z]/);
  let re = new RegExp(/[a-z]/);

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    changeMetaEmail(value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (email) {
      var Person = Parse.Object.extend("Person");
      var person = new Person();
      person.set("email", email);
      person.save();
    }
  }, [email]);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (re.test(metaEmail)) {
      changeEmail(metaEmail);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="mainContainer">
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar variant="dense">
          <Typography>{email}</Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Grid container justify="center">
        <Box classes="inputArea" margin="2rem">
          <Grid container xs="10rem">
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => {
                handleInput(e);
              }}
            ></Input>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container justify="center">
            <Box margin="10px">
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                onClick={() => {
                  handleSubmit();
                }}
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```